# Receive Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Push Notification to a UWP Windows 10 App

Tags: c#, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, win-universal-app, uwp

My client are currently using `Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)`.

I've been researching this for a while but I only seem to find examples on how to send push notification with `GCM` to android devices using `C#` but I can't find anything regarding `receiving/capturing` push notification sent from GCM to a UWP Windows 10 application?

Is this is possible?

Can it be done without having to use `Azure`? I've just checked and I can see that you can set up `GCM` in the notification hub in `Azure` but my client doesn't want to use `Azure` if at all possible and just stick to `GCM`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Cloud Messaging is an Android only Service by Google. Every OS has it's own similar Service and they are not intoperatable.

While it would be a really cool thing to have a cross platform Notification Service, I wouldn't bet on it to happen anytime soon. Notifications are deeply integrated into the OS for reasons like battery saving and security.

All current notification Systems work very similar and sending messages to them is mostly just sending some json/xml via Http. All you have to do is distinguish between android and windows targets when sending your notification and then either post it to gmc or wns.

Find information on [WNS here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Azure Notification Hubs are just a service that do exactly that for you, so you don't have to code it yourself (with some other nice extras), but they are not required to use WNS.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Kai. It is disappointing alright but understandable I guess. This means that I will need an account for Each platform but doesn't that become cumbersome? Only at researching stage at the moment, but I believe my clients mentioned that Gcm was free but I checked Azure pricing and there is a cost associated with the service, well after a 1 million push if I read that correctly. Couldn't this becomes expensive after a while having 3 platforms? Also how do I distinguish between targets when sending notifications if I decided to go with azure notification hubs? Thabks

Comment: WNS and APNS (the apple one) are free too. Azure Notification Hubs are a Value Added Service that makes sending notifications a lot easier. You don't need to use it. Windows Notifications don't have anything to do with azure (except maybe their backend runs there  )

Comment: Again, thanks additional info but I'm confused. If I don't have to use Azure, what do I need to use? I'm not sure where to start?

Comment: Windows Push Notification Service (wns). Its the exact same thing as gcm, just for Windows Devices. See the link in the answer for all details, or this quickstart guide -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868252?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks for that Kai.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as answered as you've answered my question but I'm struggling with a part of the article you provided me with. I'll probably post a question in the next few days if I still haven't figured it out. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok thank you. Next steps are really dependent on how your app backend works, so it's probably a ne question anyway. And as you have got gcm running, I believe you'll get this up too.